# How to show a custom form in a block?

Tags: 7, views, forms, blocks, ajax

I have a custom form which currently shows on a page. The form is submitted via ajax and the view embedded is also updated via ajax. I do not want to show the form on a page. Instead I want to show it in a block. I should be able to put the block anywhere on the website.

This is my form

```
/**
 * Provide a form.
 */
function MYMODULE_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['wrapper'] = [
    '#type'       => 'container',
    '#attributes' => [
      'id' => 'mywrapper',
    ],
  ];

  $form['wrapper']['node_form'] = [
    '#type'  => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Add article'),
  ];

  $form['wrapper']['node_form']['node_title'] = [
    '#type'     => 'textfield',
    '#title'    => t('Article title'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  ];

  $form['wrapper']['submit'] = [
    '#type'   => 'submit',
    '#value'  => t('Save'),
    '#submit' => ['MYMODULE_form_submit'],
    '#ajax'   => [
      'callback' => 'MYMODULE_MYCALLBACK',
      'wrapper'  => 'mywrapper',
    ],
  ];

  $form['wrapper']['view_display'] = [
    // view machine name && display/block name
    '#markup' => views_embed_view('nodes', 'block'),
  ];

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Do some validation.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Better do some validation.
  // Here or via #element_validate.
  // @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#element_validate
}

/**
 * Form submit. Node creation.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  global $user;
  $node = new stdClass();

  $node->type     = 'article';
  $node->title    = $form_state['values']['node_title'];
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $node->uid      = $user->uid;

  node_object_prepare($node);
  node_save($node);

  // Empty out title field on rebuild.
  $form_state['input']['node_title'] = '';

  // Rebuild form.
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

/**
 * Ajax callback to return the whole wrapper.
 */
function MYMODULE_MYCALLBACK($form, &$form_state) {

  return $form['wrapper'];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {

  $items['example/form'] = [
    'title'            => 'Example Form',
    'description'      => 'A form to mess around with.',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => ['MYMODULE_form'],
    'access arguments' => ['create article content'],
  ];

  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a block with [hook_block_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7.x) and embed your custom form within a block using [hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7.x). Assuming module's name to be example, this module creates a "My block" with the form.

FYI, in the below code `drupal_render(drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_form'));` is the one rendering your form in the block where **MYMODULE_form is the form ID**.

```
 <?php
    /**
     * Implements hook_block_info().
     */
    function example_block_info() {
      $blocks = array();

      $blocks['MYBLOCK'] = array(
        'info' => t('My block'), 
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
      );
      return $blocks;
    }

    /**
     * Implements hook_block_view().
     */
    function example_block_view($delta = '') {
      $block = array();

      switch ($delta) {
        case 'MYBLOCK':
          $block['subject'] = t('My block title');
          $block['content'] = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_form'));
      }
      return $block;
    }
```